# Find the generalized eigenvectors of a $3\times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image: Matrix A1]

I have calculated the eigenvalues (three times 1) and the eigenvectors however.

I have to calculate the generalized eigenvectors for this matrix. However, it turns out I am not able to calculate them properly. I am missing something, or I am making a terrible mistake during the calculation. I would be glad if someone would take the time to explain step by step how these generalized eigenvectors are calculated.

Comment: For eigen value substitute -X ,2-X,1-X in place of 0,2,1 ie trace you will get X put these values of

Comment: By putting value of new matrix =0 you get X they are eigenvalues then substitue it in AX=eigenvalue solve for X you get the eigenvectors here A is the given matrix. You can see Cayley Hamilton theorem to know how to solve for eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

The general way to do this, for a given eigenvalue $\lambda$, is to consider the sequence of subspaces:
$$0\varsubsetneq E_\lambda=\ker(A-\lambda I)\varsubsetneq\dots\varsubsetneq\ker(A-\lambda I)^{k-1} \varsubsetneq\ker(A-\lambda I)^k=\ker(A-\lambda I)^{k+1}=\dots $$
Then you choose a maximal linearly independent set of vectors in $\ker(A-\lambda I)^k\smallsetminus\ker(A-\lambda I)^{k-1} $, consider their images by $A-\lambda I$ in $\ker(A-\lambda I)^{k-1} $, complete these in a maximal set of linearly independent vectors in $\ker(A-\lambda I)^{k-1}\smallsetminus\ker(A-\lambda I)^{k-2} $, and so on, until you arrive in the eigenspace $E_\lambda$.

In the present case, the eigenspace has dimension $2$ and you have $(A-I)^2=0$, hence $\ker(A-I)^2=\mathbf R^3$. Choose a vector $v\in\mathbf R^3\smallsetminus E_1$ , set $u=(A-I)v$, and complete $v$ in another (non colinear) eigenvector $w$. You have your Jordan basis.